# VIM: How to pass arguments to functions from user commands?

Tags: vim

I am trying to create a user-defined command in VIM that takes one argument and calls a function with the user supplied argument. Seems simple but I am unable to get it to work.  Here is the code from my foo.vim plugin:

```
function! s:MyFunc(myParam)
    do something
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 MyCommand call s:MyFunc(myParam)
```

When I try this out in a VIM buffer like this:

```
:MyCommand exampleParam
```

I get the following errors:

```
E121: Undefined variable: myParam 
E116: Invalid arguments for function <SNR>7_MyFunc
```

What's wrong here? How do I fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use [`<f-args>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3Cf-args%3E):

```
command! -nargs=1 MyCommand call s:MyFunc(<f-args>)
```

Comment: I wasn't sure what the `!` meant...  it means overwrite existing command.  I found this helpful: 
http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/vim/user_commands.html
 
> `:com!`                      `Existing-cmd-name   cmd-replacement`