# Vim -- paste content of command line process referencing filename of current buffer into new buffer

Tags: svn, vim

I'm trying to create a mapping so that I can do a svn compare-with-base with a few keystrokes

I know how to do each step manually....

1. `:new` to open new buffer.
2. `:read !svn cat <filename>` To read base version of file into new buffer.
3. `:diffthis` on new buffer and previous buffer to diff the files.

I'd love to map this series of events to a mapping like `-scb`, but am not sure how to grab the filename (like `:e %<cr>`) and place it into the read command.  I'm also not sure how I can efficiently grab the output of the read command and put it in the new buffer if I'm using `%`.

Comment: How about:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213657/vim-how-to-pass-arguments-to-functions-from-user-commands

Comment: If that answers my question, I fail to see how I'm afraid.

Comment: How about this Q/A on SuperUser? http://superuser.com/questions/370125/getting-output-from-command-in-a-vim-buffer

Comment: This is probably a solved problem.  Have you looked for plugins that handle svn?  I use Tim Pope's fugitive plugin, which provides similar functionality for git instead of svn.

Comment: Thanks @benjifisher, I think that superuser answer also answers mine.  I am not so much focused on svn; I just added the tag so people searching for a similar problem thing find it. I agree it's probably been solved before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this particular question has been asked and answered on SuperUser:  https://superuser.com/questions/370125/getting-output-from-command-in-a-vim-buffer

For the sake of general vim education, read on.

There are at least three ways to access the current file name.  On the command line,

```
:e! %
```

will reload the current file, although it is simpler to use just `:e!`.  A more useful example, using filename modifiers, is to edit `foo.h` if you are currently editing `foo.c`:

```
:sp %:r.h
```

The second way is to use the `@%` register, which is a String variable with the name of the current file (relative to the current directory).

```
:let myfile = @%
:let mypath = fnamemodify(@%, ':p')
```

The third way is to use `expand()`:

```
:let myfile = expand("%")
:let mypath = expand("%:p")
```

There are some differences between `fnamemodify()` and `expand()`.

```
:help cmdline-special
:help @%
:help @#
:help fnamemodify()
:help expand()
```

Comment: Interesting, although I noticed that the other question used # instead of %; I tried :r !svn cat % and it didn't work, but :r !svn cat # did.  Despite reading :help a bit, still don't know why; I guess # is the alternate filename, but I would have thought current filename was perfectly fine.

Comment: Also, in case the superuser link dies, the answer was ":new | r !svn diff #" to do everything I wanted.

Comment: @AlexMA `#` is the alternate file. `:h alternate-file`. If there already was a current file name, then that one becomes the alternate
file name and it can be referenced with `#`.

Comment: Right.  So you could do something like `:let path = expand('%:p')`, then `:new`, then `:let mypath = expand('#:p')`, and check that `path` is the same as `mypath` with `:echo path == mypath`.