# vim cmap lhs only at the beginning

Tags: vim

I have a mapping 
`:cnoremap ch call ShowHistoryMatching`

The problem is that the `ch` characters expand to the right sentence in any case they are typed, no matter if at the beginning or later in the cmap input.

The problem is when I try to search for words in vim using `/` or `?` e.g. for
`/cache` - it will be expanded using the mapping above.

How can I set the mapping ch to be extended only when it occurs at the beginning of the command?

Comment: how about make use of `normal mode map` instead? `:nnoremap <leader>ch :call YourFunc()<CR>`

Comment: It might be a working approach to bypass the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmap`'s are notoriously tricky because they often execute in the wrong context. Some better alternatives:

- Use a normal mapping e.g. `nnoremap <leader>ch :call ShowHistoryMatching()<cr>`
- Create a command e.g. `command Ch call ShowHistoryMatching()`
- Use a the [cmdalias.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746) plugin
- Use a more clever abbreviation as described in [vim change :x function to delete buffer instead of save & quit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7515418/438329) post. Similar technique to cmdailias.vim.

Personally I would just create a new command.

Comment: You showed approaches for my issue. I read about 3rd and 4th now and might read later. I'll stay with 1st approach for now and if it will be annoying I'll switch to the others. Thank you.

Comment: I use the command solution combined with <f-args>  as found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3213800/428399

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getcmdpos()` function to determine if you're at the beginning of the line or somewhere else. This technique can [replace a built-in command using an abbreviation](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_builtin_command_using_cabbrev) or you can adapt it for use in a mapping, possibly with an `<expr>` mapping.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I decided to use the command solution combined with <f-args> as found here: stackoverflow.com/a/3213800/428399