# How to perform operation (e.g. `dd`) on a line without moving the cursor to that line in Vim?

Tags: vim

> How to perform operation (e.g. `dd`) on a line without moving the cursor to that line in Vim?

Suppose I want to perform some operation on line `n` (e.g. `dd`) and the cursor is currently on line `m`.

Normally, I would do as follows:

- goto line `n` (`:n`)
- delete line `n` (`dd`)
- go back to line `m` (`:m`) (+/-1 offset)

Indeed, it must be possible to delete line `n` without moving the cursor twice using `:`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:nd` (`n` being the line number) followed by `ctrl+o`.

This is one of the quirks with vim that I am still struggeling with. I feel, a `:range` command should not move the cursor at all.

Comment: Nice job, can you explain it? `:n` is obvious, but why only `d` and not `dd`? Also, what is the effect of `C-o` in general?

Comment: `dd` is a normal mode command while `:[range]d` is an ex mode command - and both happen to delete one or more lines. The `:nd` command adds the current postion to the jump list and then jumps to the deleted line. `ctrl-o` jumps back to the last position in the jump list.

Comment: By "ex mode" you mean "visual mode", or is "ex mode" some exotic mode I've never encounted?

Comment: Ex mode is entered with `:`. Another small window will open where you can type your ex command.

Comment: Is `ex` an abbreviation of "execute"? Can you tell me what to search for in `:help` in order to get all commands like `d`, I can use in `ex` mode? I guess, I can yank, paste etc.

Comment: [ex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor)) is a line oriented text editor whose *vi*sual interface became *vi*. vi retained the functionality of *ex* in its ex mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a "Preserve function" and even make it a command like this:

```
if !exists('*Preserve')
    function! Preserve(command)
        try
            let l:win_view = winsaveview()
             "silent! keepjumps keeppatterns execute a:command
            silent! execute 'keeppatterns keepjumps ' . a:command
        finally
            call winrestview(l:win_view)
        endtry
    endfunction
endif

command! -nargs=1 Preserve call Preserve(<f-args>)
```

Just in case you are using relative numbers you can run:

```
:Preserve +13d
```

The function preserve allows you to do many other things like:

```
" define a command for reindenting the code without moving the cursor 
command! -nargs=0 Reindent :call Preserve('exec "normal! gg=G"')
" Remove trailing whitespaces
call Preserve(":%s,\\s\\+$,,e")
```

Sources: 
+ https://technotales.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/preserve-a-vim-function-that-keeps-your-state/
+ https://stackoverflow.com/a/3213800/2571881